# How do I include another graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I want to include a threshold and want to see which bars have crossed it.

Answer (score 0):

First save the return value of the call to df.plot:

`ax = df_6.plot(...)`

Now you have a reference to the plot (`ax` is a matplotlib Axis object that represents the plot you just made). You can then add a horizontal line to the plot like this:

`ax.axhline(y=5, color='red')`